# How to change font properties of a control (e.g. label) at runtime

Tags: fonts, visual-c++-2008

I've got the need to change the font properties of the text in a Label and in an Item of a ListView during runtime. I thought it was easy, writing:

```
label1->font->Bold=true;
```

But its not possible, because 'Bold' has just got a get() but no set() method. Infact, the compiler doesn't accept it:

```
error C2039: 'set': its not a  member of 'System::Drawing::Font::Bold'
```

Is there any other possibility to influence the font of a text in a Label or Item of a ListView? And if Yes, which one is it?

Thanks 4 Your help

Comment: A part of it I found out myself: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle%28v=vs.90%29.aspx].    But this solution just allows me to set the fontStyle to Bold or Underline or Italic... But in some cases I want it UNDERLINE, _italic_ AND **Bold**. How can I manage to do that?

Comment: A part of it I found out myself: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle%28v=vs.90%29.aspx].    'label1->Font = gcnew System::Drawing::Font( FontFamily::GenericSansSerif,12.0F,FontStyle::Bold );'            But this solution just allows me to set the fontStyle to Bold or Underline or Italic... But in some cases I want it UNDERLINE, _italic_ AND **Bold**. How can I manage to do that?